# PHP Readline: Get a new prompt on SIGINT

Tags: php, signals, readline, pcntl

I'm writing a **php cli** interactive program, it act as a shell by using `readline` extension.

But I find that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, the whole program exits. I hope it can get a new prompt instead of exit (just like `bash`).

So I try `pcntl_signal` to handle the `SIGINT`

```
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

It doesn't exit and response nothing (just like dead)

I change the code to:

```
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, function(){
    echo "\n";
});
```

This time it prints `^C` but no new line, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> these is a new line before the prompt.

I have read [Readline: Get a new prompt on SIGINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828378/readline-get-a-new-prompt-on-sigint) , but it's using `C`, and I found there is no `siglongjmp` function in `php`.

So I wonder is it possible to get a new prompt when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>